# How to apply the same configuration to some UILabel in iOS?

Tags: ios, iphone, cocoa-touch

I am tired of setting property values to each `UILabel` in the IB. Is extending the `UILabel` the only possible way? or there exists some other way to do it?

Comment: At first connect with IBOutlet and then from coding you can set configuration with many labels.

Comment: Use category - create one method and then set properties in that method.

Comment: put your sample screen to understand ??

Comment: Please mark any of the answers as accepted if it helped you.

Answer (score 0):

- Assign all the properties to one UILabel
- Copy paste the label as many times you want in storyboard or xib
- New labels will also get the same properties, you just require to arrange their positions
- Then you can go ahead with IBOutlets and manipulate with those

This applies to all the widgets in storyboard/xib.

Also as **@dehlen** metioned,

If you are using codebase for UI then,  **Custom Button Class**

- Inherit UIButton and create a subclass `CustomButton`
- In its init method, assign all the properties which you require, like font, color etc
- And assign frame value at use-time, through initWithFrame method.
  Or
- Add button in storyboard/xib, but in its class property change class name to `CustomButton`

Thanks @dehlen, You are right, I forgot to mention code side implementation.

Comment: If he doesn't use the IB but creates his UI elements programmatically he could also use a subclass or better a category.

Comment: No style like thing as in android here?

Comment: @Sarasranglt : If you are having such common widgets in much more numbers, then I would suggest you to go with 2nd option.

Answer (score 0):

You could create an `IBOuletCollection` for the labels and set the properties programmatically (in `viewDidLoad` for example) using:

```
[self.outletCollection setValue:whatever forKey:something];
```

You can also call `makeObjectsPerformSelector` on the collection in order to send messages to each label.

Answer (score 0):

After setting the property of a **UILabel** make **copy** of it by

Press and hold alt and drag and drop **UILabel** to another place it will create new copy of that UILabel with same properties.